# How to export large matrix from .nb file into .pdf

Tags: export, pdf-format, printing

I have one technical problem with printing large matrix 50x50 with lot of data.
Always when I want to export .nb to .pdf, I can see just part of matrix, never all.

Is there solution for this? I need to present data, but not in a .nb file.
It is easy to do scrolling left or right in a .nb file - but how to print the whole matrix to a .pdf file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Export to pdf via `File -> Save As...` exports to A4-size pdf document, but with `Export[]`, this is not (automatically) the case.

So, if you have this data:

```
array = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {50, 50}]
```

...this command will give you a full view of your array in a pdf document:

```
Export["test.pdf", Grid[array]]
```